# angular2 CanActivate with http

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I am having a component that has canactivate

```
import {isLoggedIn} from '../login/isLoginedIn';

@CanActivate((next, previous) => {
 isLoggedIn()
})
```

My "isLoggedIn" is as below

```
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

class Auth {
    constructor( @Inject(Http)  private _http: Api) { }

    check() {
        this._http.get('/Users/LoggedInUser')
    }
}

export const isLoggedIn = () => {
    let injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([Auth, Http]);
    let auth = injector.get(Auth);
    return auth.check(); 
};
```

I can't inject a service which has http as dependancy. Can this be done like this or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `CanActivate` is a decorator instead of a method as with `OnActivate` or `CanDeactivate` then you are correct in assuming that constructor dependency injection of the component that you are attempting to authorize is not an option.

The method which you are using will work, but there is a missed `@Injectable()` on your `Auth` class.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
class Auth {
    constructor( @Inject(Http)  private _http: Api) { }

    check() {
        this._http.get('/Users/LoggedInUser')
    }
}
```

This approach is sound and I don't think that besides some syntactic sugar or minor refactoring that there would be much to improve this and still achieve the same amount of readability / maintainability for this approach.

One other addition that could be made to improve the flow and prevent a potential bug would be to return the observable in `CanActivate` so that the navigation will wait for the `Http` request to complete before deciding to continue or cancel.

```
@CanActivate((next, previous) => {
    return isLoggedIn()
})
```

or for short

```
@CanActivate(() => isLoggedIn())
```

*(Single statement arrow functions are auto-returning)*

Comment: Great answer but `CanActivate` is a decorator (instead of a directive), no? ;-)

Comment: Is there anyway to set a property on the Component that has the @CanActivate? Say the isLoggedIn also returns the user and you want to throw that on the Component?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier You are completely right, I mist have been tired last night. Will update wording. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: @Primm I would recommend caching the value of `user` in the `Auth` service and then once the component is activated you can simply pull the value from it. Nevertheless I would recommend asking a new question here on SO if you would like more options.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier As always feel free to edit my answers if you catch anything. In my opinion we're all in this together as a community.